# Java code does not run using 'script' package in Atom, but runs fine using terminal

Tags: java, atom-editor, javac

I have a simple Java program that I believe is not the problem, but I will post it anyway because i am new to Java.

```
class myclass{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Hello Java");
  }
}
```

When using terminal and typing `java filename.java` this runs fine. But when I tried running it from inside Atom code editor, using the [`script` package](https://github.com/atom-community/atom-script#script), i get this error message:

```
error: invalid flag: Mylastname\Desktop\kode
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

Since my username consists of my first and last name, with a space in between, I think this may be a problem with whitespace? But I have no idea on how to fix it, is there a way?

Comment: I might have a workaround. Try this: do **Script: Run Options** (Atom command `script:run-options`) and in **Command Arguments**, put `"{FILE_ACTIVE}"`, then **Run**.

Comment: It looks like this is a known bug: [Error while running scripts whose path contains whitespaces.](https://github.com/atom-community/atom-script/issues/2185)

Comment: Thanks, that worked, for others who might see this post, remember to put `java` in the commandfield aswell